# Unityscript: How to avoid memory leaks when using Tasks instead of Threads?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, task

When I run the following code as a thread it runs fine with no memory leak.  The problem with this is that I have multiple routines like this running and it causes CPU usage to be higher.  This runs on a fanless PC so I want it to be as low as possible.  Changing it to tasks I see a drop from 40% to less than 30% CPU usage.

This is how I call it using a thread

```
dbThread = new Thread(DBupdater)
{
    IsBackground = true
};
dbThread.Start();


/// <summary>
/// Updates the data to the database
/// </summary>
private void DBupdater()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (eqLock)
        {
            changes = ErrorQue.FindAll(c => c.Status != (char)RowStatus.NoChange);
        }
        if (changes.Count > 0)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection(DB.SQLiteConString))
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand sqlText = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (var row in changes)
                    {
                        if (row.Status != (char)RowStatus.NoChange)
                        {
                            lock (eqLock)
                            {
                                //Build the SQL for the changes
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (sqlText.CommandText != null)
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        sqlText.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            changes.Clear();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

This is how I run it as a task.  This causes a leak.

```
private CancellationTokenSource runTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
private void Start()
{
    TaskEx.Repeat(DBupdater, 100, runTokenSource.Token);
}

public static void Repeat(Action action, int milliSeconds, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (action == null) return;

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            action();
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested) await Task.Delay(milliSeconds, token);
        }
    }, token);
}

/// <summary>
/// Updates the data to the database
/// </summary>
private void DBupdater()
{
        lock (eqLock)
        {
            changes = ErrorQue.FindAll(c => c.Status != (char)RowStatus.NoChange);
        }
        if (changes.Count > 0)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection(DB.SQLiteConString))
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand sqlText = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (var row in changes)
                    {
                        if (row.Status != (char)RowStatus.NoChange)
                        {
                            lock (eqLock)
                            {
                                //Build the SQL for the changes
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (sqlText.CommandText != null)
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        sqlText.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            changes.Clear();
        }
}
```

I have tried multiple ways of running it as a task but they have all caused leaks that eventually crash the program.

This is one of the ways I have tried

```
private async Task RunUpdater()
{
    While(true)
    {
        await DBupdater();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```